# How to programmatically get Facebook's test user's access token in Python?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have tried to do a GET request to https://graph.facebook.com/{app-id}/accounts/test-users?access_token={app-id}|{app-secret}.

This returns a JSON response with all the test users that are associated with the app and their access_tokens. However, each JSON "page" only contained up to 25 id so I have to iterate through several pages.

My code took longer than 5 minutes and it was still running. Is there a more optimal way to get the access token programmatically (Python)?

Comment: I dealt with the same issue and haven't found a solution either. The only thing i could do was to delete all the other test users after my tests are run.